# How to annotate a numpy array of strings with mypy?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I'm using a numpy array to store **pairs of strings** in order to take advantage of numpy array's memory view capability when slicing,which normal python lists don't have.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

pairs_of_identifiers = np.array([['A11', 'A19'], ['A2', 'A6'], ...]])

random_function(pairs_of_identifiers: npt.NDArray[str]) -> None:
    ...
```

So far I have tried to annotate it as `npt.NDArray[str]`, but I get the following pylance/mypy error:

```
Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
  Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
    "str" is incompatible with "generic"
```

What is the correct way of annotating a NDarray of strings with mypy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Built-in scalar types](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types):

> | Array scalar type | Related Python type | Inherits? |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `int_` | `int` | Python 2 only |
> | `float_` | `float` | yes |
> | `complex_` | `complex` | yes |
> | `bytes_` | `bytes` | yes |
> | `str_` | `str` | yes |
> | `bool_` | `bool` | no |
> | `datetime64_` | `datetime.datetime` | no |
> | `timedelta64` | `datetime.timedelta` | no |

So you can use `npt.NDArray[np.str_]`.